# How do I run test on different environments in Play Framework 2.1.1?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, playframework-2.0

I know there are lots of similar questions around this area I tried them all and it didn't work. Plus, it seems to be ok for just `play run` command

I setup Jenkins which will use the database from RDS. Local development will be using MySQL localhost. But I seem to cannot run the test in different configuration file. It always looks for application.conf

This is my application.conf

```
...
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass=""
db.default.logStatements=true
...
```

And this is my ci.conf

```
include "application.conf"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://${ENDPOINT_TO_RDS}/mydb"
db.default.user=username
db.default.pass=password
db.default.logStatements=true
...
```

But when I run `play -Dconfig.file=conf/ci.conf test` My tests still look for application.conf. I confirm this by putting a wrong password in application.conf.

Comment: Check this question for suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/q/15885814/1066240

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but overriding parameter seems to work only for "play start/run" command but it doesn't work for "play test" command which I don't quite understand.

Comment: Yes, I suggested there to override in params in application.conf temporary as it's definitely bug, sorry that have no better answer, maybe for an example Igor's answer can help you? BTW it would be good idea to check if there's no ticket in the lighthouse and create one if required: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview

Comment: P.S. Just found: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/981-overriding-configuration-for-tests with status `wontfix`

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15637279/2153190